# Translate press Wordpress plugin Issue

Tags: wordpress, plugins, translation, french

Im trying to use the Wordpress plugin TranslatePress however the French Version of the page https://fr.londonauto.autoverify.com/fr/backend-glitch/ doesn't seam to play well with the page content.

I cant see anything relevant to the issue in the console.

Works without issue in the english version - https://fr.londonauto.autoverify.com/backend-glitch/

Wondering if anyone out there has experience with this plugin that might be able to advise.

Answer (score -1):

It's obvious that in the /fr/ lang you missing to load many-many files. Your total requests are 104 for this page and in the FR you load only 42. It's very strange problem and I think that it has to do with you htaccess file. Can you please describe your server options, like: Cache system, Webserver type, etc? Also post your redirect rules if you have nginx or apache

Comment: Forgive me Im a little bit lacking on knowledge on the server side of things. Its on a dedicated server with hostgator and Here is the answer they gave me to your questions

memcached and PHP-FPM with Zend OPCache.
Apache 2, Apache Cassandra, and Apache Flex also works on your server.

1. CentOS 64 bit Linux with full root access (Ubuntu 16.04,18.04,and 20.04 installs available on request).
2. cPanel with WHM control panel1
3. Apache Web Server, MySQL, PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby (on Rails), FFmpeg support
5. Secured server with IPtables firewall